# Problem displaying a form inside of a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a simple app and have ran into an issue when trying to display a form in a panel. So the form I am trying to display has 1 line of text on it saying 'New Quote' (this isn't what I will displaying eventually, just testing to try make this display). I open the form in my panel and it displays an empty form with nothing on it. Not sure why there is no text being displayed saying 'New Quote'.

The code I am using to display the form in a panel:

```
        newForm1 frm = new newForm1();
        frm.TopLevel = false;
        //frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.splitContainerAdv1.Panel2.Controls.Add(frm);
        frm.Show();
```

I have commented out the FormBorderStyle as it shows the issue more easily I believe.

[What currently happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfPlC.png)

[The form I am opening and what I expect to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UKns.png)

Comment: There is no obvious reason for that.  It is technically possible for a child control to never get painted. Happens when a paint event for a control or parent lower in the Z-order keeps invalidating the control.  The most visible side-effect of such a bug is that the UI thread of your program burns 100% core.   I suspect most SO users would recommend you using a UserControl instead.

Comment: Whitout knowing what he is doing while adding the form, we can not give him propper advice :-(

Comment: Aboslutely nothing while adding the form I have a button click event, that runs the code I have shown above and displays the form in the panel, I'm not sure what other information I can provide?

Comment: so you simply have the main form with a button on it and the child form with a label on it and when the button click event of the main form is executed your code comes in? That is not much different to my code, except I took the form shown event to test your code... (not Form load as i mentioned below)

Comment: Yes, this is whats confusing me everything I've seen or read is telling me this should work, but its just simply not